# Display the area which belongs to both divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three divs, please check my code.

```
<div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>

#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  zoom: 150%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkstorm/j77L7v9L/11/) 
As you can see, div2 overlaps div1.
I can zoom in and zoom out div2.
What I want to do is to display the area which belongs to both divs and hide the other parts of div2 [image]

The yellow area is displayed, and the blue areas is hidden.
How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [CSS Clipping](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) and use a rectangle to display only the overlapping portion of div2.

Comment: Showing brief examples in the actual post will help you get marked with a good answer :)

Comment: @Mike Skott If I use CSS Clipping, although I recalculate clip-path value while zooming in and out div2, nonoverlapping portion of div2 is showed.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much!